# How can I optimize a WordPress website except minifying files and compressing images?

Tags: wordpress, optimization

I am trying to optimize a WordPress website. I already minified some js and CSS files. I already tried compressing images and videos and trying to eliminate render-blocking files but the website speed is just the same.

The issue that I found on the website is that it has files that are too long and even I enabled caching, some files are not being cached.

Any information or website that will be helpful to optimize the website?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the following instructions:

1. take a backup of your file.
2. Install a cache plugin like as [https://wp-rocket.me/[1]
3. minify css,html,js of your wordpress file

This plugin is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a backup of your site manually
Go to public_html and compress all the files
After that export a copy of the database by phpMyAdmin

Then you can perform the following steps:

- Clean the database where there is a lot of data that could be cached You can do this with several plugins (I recommend :[WP-Optimize - Cache, Clean, Compress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/))
- After you clean and optimize the database, deactivate this plugin and install the [WP Fastest Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/) plugin
  Include the following options (note that you must turn off any other speed booster plug-ins because including more than one speed plugin can cause negative interference):

-cach system

-preload

-logged-in Users

-Minify HTML

-Gzip

-Drowser caching

-Disable Emojis

*Notice:
preload
Enable – This tells the plugin to preload your pages. Upon firing, you'll get a popup asking you which pages to cache.
Check all the categories – Particularly Home
page, Posts, Categories, Pages

Leave the “pages per minute” at 4
You may need to reduce this number depending on your hosting provider limits.

Leave the “Restart After Completed” option unchecked.*

After you do that, compress the images with any compression plugin (i use smush)
Then go and test your site here https://gtmetrix.com/

This article https://gtmetrix.com/wordpress-optimization-guide.html
I have benefited a lot from it on my personal site and it has reached 96% speed because of these tips